# How to use lambda function as a argument properly?

Tags: javascript, typescript

If I have a statement like:

`public startDate = this.formatDate(new Date());`

I would like to instead of passing new Date(), pass a date created by a function. I know I can do:

`public startDate = this.formatDate(this.getDateFunc());`

But is there a way to do it with a lambda function? I tried looking it up, but all the posts I found were talking about function as a parameter in the definition.

I want to do something like:

`public startDate = this.formatDate(() => {...});`

Comment: "*But is there a way to do it with a lambda function? I tried looking it up, but all the posts I found were talking about function as a parameter in the definition*" lambdas (arrow functions) **are** functions. [There are some differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/are-arrow-functions-and-functions-equivalent-exchangeable) but none that probably matter for having one as a parameter.

Comment: ^ Note that an arrow function is not necessarily a lambda. A lambda is an anonymous function. When you save a arrow function into a variable it's no longer anonymous, thus no longer a lambda. For example `n => n * 2` is a lambda, but `const double = n => n * 2` is not a lambda. Some might say that the latter is still an unnamed function and thus a lambda, but this depends on your definition of anonymous.

Comment: @VLAZ thanks, very helpful. So basically, in any scenario where you could syntactically use a function reference, you can also use a arrow function?

Comment: @rustytoaster21 correct. There is no difference between functions and arrow functions as far as when can they be used. The difference is how they interact with other stuff - mostly arrow functions don't have their own `this` but use the lexical one, while normal functions can have their own `this` value. But that's not always relevant - if you take a parameter `fn` and execute it as `fn(someArg)` it would still work whether `fn` is an arrow function or a normal function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming, from your example, that you're wanting an anonymous function call. If so, yes, you can do this with an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE):

```js
public startDate = this.formatDate(
    (() => {
        // do some other stuff
        return new Date(/* ...args */)
    })()
)
```

However, it's typically better for readability to name the function.

Answer (score 0):

```
class A {
  public startDate = this.dateFactory();

  constructor(
    private dateFactory,
  ) {}

  ...
}
// somewhere in code
new A(() => new Date());
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
type GetDate = () => Date

const formatDate = (getDate: GetDate) => {
 const date = getDate()
 // formate date
 
}

// usage
const getDateFromInternet = () => API.getDate() // imaginary API which fetches date

const formattedDate = formatDate(getDateFromInternet)
```